# Override for Simplenews is not working

Tags: theming

I tried to follow the instructions for custom newsletter theme and it told me to copy and paste simplenews-newsletter-body.html.twig into my custom theme folder. But on sending test emails it doesnt render the changes that I have made in the file thats in my custom theme folder.

Comment: Cleared cache ? Are you sure the theme is picked up when sending the newsletter ? Perhaps you need to add this template to the theme that is used when viewing/sending the newsletter

Comment: @GiorgosK I found the solution. I had to make changes in my mailing system it was set to current and I had to set it on my theme. Thanks for your help.